# Compare two arrays and list common entries

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following two arrays:

```
userStatus
---------------
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (      
            [Username] => cynthia@test.net
            [Status] => Active
        )

    [1] => Array
        (           
            [Username] => mary@test.net
            [Status] => Terminated
        )

    [2] => Array
        (           
            [Username] => steve@test.net
            [Status] => OnVacation
        )
)

users
------
Array
(
    [0] => steve@test.net
    [1] => mark@test.net
    [2] => cynthia@test.net
)
```

I want to write a snippet that brings up an array of all userStatus entries that match on Username field in the users Array.

I can achieve this through a double for loop running and comparing both arrays, but is there a fast way to do this using PHP inbuilt array functions or any other way?

Comment: did you look at array_filter() or array_map() functions?

Comment: You got this stuff here `array_intersect` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP >= 5.3 then you could use array_filter with an anonymous callback function... Not particularly efficient, but simple.

```
$userStatus=array(
        array(
            'Username' => 'cynthia@test.net',
            'Status' => 'Active'
        ),
        array(
            'Username' => 'mary@test.net',
            'Status' => 'Terminated'
        ),
        array(
            'Username' => 'steve@test.net',
            'Status' => 'OnVacation'
        ));

$users = array(
     'steve@test.net',
     'mark@test.net',
     'cynthia@test.net'
);


$filtered = array_filter($userStatus, function ($var) {
 global $users;
 return in_array($var['Username'], $users);
});

print_r($filtered);
```

If you're after something a little quicker, then convert the user array into a "map", by changing the values to keys, then check if a key is set in the callback.

```
$userlookup = array_flip($users);

$filtered = array_filter($userStatus, function ($var) {
 global $userlookup;
 return isset($userlookup[$var['Username']]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want it **fast**, set the users array like this:

```
$users = array(
    'steve@test.net' => 1,
    'mark@test.net' => 1,
    'cynthia@test.net' => 1
);
```

Then just check if the array index is set:

```
$matched = array();
foreach($userStatus as $k => $v) {
    if(isset($users[$v['Username']])) {
        $matched[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
foreach($matched as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k = ".$v['Username']." is ".$v['Status']."<br>";
}
```